# How to display message after onClick button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

My onClick button already runs a function after I click it, I just want it to also display a confirmation message after being clicked. I'm just stuck. Any help is appriciated.
This is how my button is formatted:

```
<button id="button" type="button" onClick={write}> 
    RESERVE ROOM
  </button>
```

Comment: Is write is a function you have defined?

Comment: its a constant with a function written in it

Answer (score 0):

Just create a write function that adds the message to an html element

```js
function write() {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerText = "This is the inserted message";
}
```

Comment: What element would have the id "message"?

Comment: Add a simple element `<div id="message"></div>`. This is just a tag which contains the message in it.

Comment: I keep getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null"